# Trigger grunt livereload partway through watch task list

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a grunt task that watches for changes in CSS files before reloading. I run two tasks to generate the CSS. The first '`styles`' task creates the main.css file which I want to watch for changes to and the reload the page.

Everything works, except that the reload isn't triggered until the second  '`styles_old_ie`' task is completed. Is there a way of triggering the reload after the '`styles`' task has finished, but before the '`styles_old_ie`' task has started?

I've also tried splitting the `watch:sass` task into two tasks, but the `watch:css` task is still ran last.

```
watch: {
    css: {
        files: ['main.css', '!old-ie.css'],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    },
    sass: {
        files: ['*.scss'],
        tasks: ['styles','styles_old_ie']
    }
}
```

I want the reload to happen as soon as the main.css file is ready. I still want the other tasks to run but I don't want to have to wait for them to complete before the reload.